# How to re-initialize an attribute when shallow copying an object

Tags: python, copy, uuid

I have this simple mixin that assigns a new uuid to any new instance:

```
import uuid
import copy

class UuidMixin:
   def __new__(cls):
      obj = super().__new__(cls)
      obj.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
      return obj

class Foo(UuidMixin):
   pass

f = Foo()
```

All works well, until I decide to shallow copy the instance `f`:

```
f2 = copy.copy(f)
f.uuid == f2.uuid  # is True :(
```

But I want `f2` to have its own uuid, since it's a new object.

The obvious way to do this is to define a `__copy__` method, e.g.

```
class UuidMixin:
   def __new__(cls):
      obj = super().__new__(cls)
      obj.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
      return obj

   def __copy__(self):
      obj = self.__class__.__new__(self.__class__)
      # I *could* return `obj` here if the class hadn't any attr but `uuid`
      d = copy.copy(self.__dict__)
      d.pop('uuid')
      self.__dict__.update(d)
      return obj
```

This works, but does not seem to be a robust solution: what if I need to define `Foo.__copy__`, or even another `__copy__` method further on the inheritance tree? I all cases, I will need to remember that there is this special `uuid` attribute, that needs a special treatment while copying.

I can't seem to find any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Ideally, a mixin should not be responsible for knowing how to copy an instance of an arbitrary class; it would just use `super().__copy__` to make the copy, then assign a new UUID to the result. This requires, I think, some nontrivial work to ensure that some class in the MRO *after* `UuidMixin` implements `__copy__`, though.

Comment: (By nontrivial, I mean that given `class Foo(UuidMixin): ...`, it's not sufficient for `Foo.__copy__` to exist, because it would be called *before* `UuidMixin.__copy__` is called, and `object.__copy__` does not exist.)

Answer (score 0):

I might try to answer my own question, but it does raise another one...
The answer lies in the `__getstate__` method:

```
class UuidMixin:
   def __new__(cls):
      obj = super().__new__(cls)
      obj.uuid = uuid.uuid4()
      return obj

   def __getstate__(self):
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        del state["uuid"]
        return state
```

This works as intendent. More or less: we run into problems if e.g. multiple inheritance is involved.

But the new main issue is that of pickling: the same method `__getstate__` is called when pickling the instance of `Foo`. The desired behavior is: don't shallow copy the uuid, but do pickle/unpickle it (which does not happen with this solution).

From what I gather, **the copy protocol and the pickling protocol are one and the same.** Isn't that a violation of the Single-Responsability Principle?

The [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) documentation says:

> As we shall see, pickle does not use directly the methods described
> above [`__getstate__`, `__setstate__`]. In fact, these methods are
> part of the copy protocol which implements the `__reduce__()` special
> method.

But I can't find any further explanations.

Do you have any ideas how to decouple the copy and pickle protocols? I had some success by inspecting the callstack from inside `__getstate__`, but I'm not sure I like the idea.